# How do I serialize read-only objects in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, serialization, datacontractserializer, deserialization

I'm having a problem now: for serializing/deserializing an object which has only getters marked as `public` with `DataContractSerializer` I have to use `[InternalsVisibleTo]` attribute and to make setters `internal`.

How can I avoid this ugly workaround to get my read-only objects successfully serialized/deserialized? Implementing `ISerializable`/`IXmlSerializable` is the last thing I want to do. Do I have any other ways to do this?

Thanks in advance.
Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up with IXmlSerializable.